# New IQ Option Messages in Microsoft Edge even though I've never used their service

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

All of a sudden I started receiving pop-ups on my Windows PC from this company IQ Option offering virtual money and demo time.

Why are they messaging me through my Microsoft Edge browser? I didn't even visit their website or open an account.

Some of their pop-ups say I have missed calls. That sounds fishy since I've never used the platform.

Comment: You've probably given some shady website permission to show popups to you. Just go to `edge://settings/content/popups` and remove any unwanted sites from the list.

Comment: Are you sure that the message is actually coming from them? Maybe you inadvertently allowed some unrelated site to push messages to you and they now use this to deliver advertisements from various sources to you